# RxJS forkJoin of chained requests?

Tags: rxjs

I have

```
const jobsToRun = this.config.data.tests.map(test => test.location);
const jobsSubmits: any[] = jobsToRun
    .map(job => this.jobsService.submitTestJob(job).pipe(first())); // HERE

const finito = await forkJoin(jobsSubmits).toPromise();
```

so I submit tests in parallel and wait for all the submissions to complete. I'd like to improve this in a way, that test gets submitted and with data from the response (submission), update to database (another call) is made.

How do I best implement this forkJoin(submitTest -> make a record about the submission in database)? I suppose I just don't know which RxJS operator would be ideal.

Doing it after `finito` is resolved is not feasible, I need the record to be in the database as soon as possible after the individual test is submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ought to be a simple matter of switchMap the result of your first call into your second call.

Something like this:

```js
const jobsSubmits = this.config.data.tests
  .map(test => test.location)
  .map(job => this.jobsService.submitTestJob(job).pipe(
    first(),
    switchMap(submitted => this.jobsService.makeRecordABout(submitted))
  ));

const finito = await forkJoin(jobsSubmits).toPromise();
```

Comment: What are the benefits (if any) of switchMap vs. concatMap? I've read about the operators, but don't see much difference in my particular case, since my submit emits 2 values (same, due to flaw in design which is not under my jurisdiction, so I utilize first() to always have 1 value) it doesn't matter if I wait or not

Comment: Yeah, `first()` takes the first value and completes the stream. Under those circumstances, `mergeMap`, `concatMap`, and `switchMap` all produce identical output. `switchMap` is the only one of these 3 that doesn't manage more than one subscription at a time regardless, so it tends to get used in this cirumstance as it "feels" like the best fit.  Realistically, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `submitTestJob` is a remote http call which returns an Observable.
If this is true, I would do something like this

```
const jobsSubmits = jobsToRun
    .map(job => this.jobsService.submitTestJob(job).pipe(
          // if submitTestJob is an http call, then first should not be necessary
          first(),
          // addRecord is a function which returns an Observable which emits when
          // the record is added
          concatMap(submission => addRecord(submission))
       )
    );
```

You may read more about typical rxjs patterns with http in [this article](https://medium.com/me/stats/post/ef636c9af19a).